# How to save Standalone unity player configuration on JetBrains Rider?

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, rider

I'm using JetBrains Rider 2022.2 to debug a standalone unity player.
To connect to the running process, I go to Run -> Attach to Unity Process.
A new window opens and then I click "Add player address manually". I input the host and port, click ok and then Rider successfully connects to the running player.

The problem is, Rider doesn't save this configuration automatically, so every time I want to debug my application, I have to go through the whole song and dance above.

Is there a way to save this configuration or speed up this process?

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no clue about Unity  but in Rider, I found this:
[image]

Does this help you?

Comment: No, in my case I'm not actually attaching to a unity editor, I'm attaching to a running process, so these Run/Debug Configurations don't work